# How to find floating point exceptions in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell

Suppose a large and complicated Haskell program produces a NaN sometime during the execution. How do I find where in my code this happened without spending a lot of time adding lots of NaN checks to my code? I'm only interested in debugging, so I don't care about portability or performance.

This was discussed five years ago on Haskell-cafe. A possible solution was proposed, but wasn't discussed further.
https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/091858.html

Below is my attempt to get a stack trace to the point where a NaN is generated (in a small example program) by using `feenableexcept` as suggested in the Haskell-cafe discussion:

```
-- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Control-Functions.html
foreign import ccall "feenableexcept" enableFloatException :: Int -> IO Int

allFloatExceptions :: Int
allFloatExceptions = 1 {-INVALID-} + 4 {-DIVBYZERO-} + 8 {-OVERFLOW-} + 16 {-UNDERFLOW-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- enableFloatException allFloatExceptions

  print $ (0/0 :: Double)
```

Unfortunately, running this code doesn't produce a stack trace :(

```
$ ghc -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto testNaN.hs && ./testNaN +RTS -xc
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testNaN.hs, testNaN.o )
Linking testNaN ...
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I assume (but really have no idea) that I don't get a stack trace because the GHC runtime wasn't in control when the exception aborted the program. So next I tried using `installHandler` from `System.Posix.Signals` to try to make the program crash within GHC's runtime:

```
import qualified System.Posix.Signals as Signals

-- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Control-Functions.html
foreign import ccall "feenableexcept" enableFloatException :: Int -> IO Int

allFloatExceptions :: Int
allFloatExceptions = 1 {-INVALID-} + 4 {-DIVBYZERO-} + 8 {-OVERFLOW-} + 16 {-UNDERFLOW-}

catchFloatException :: IO ()
catchFloatException = error "print stack trace?"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  _ <- enableFloatException allFloatExceptions
  _ <- Signals.installHandler Signals.floatingPointException (Signals.Catch catchFloatException) Nothing

  print $ (0/0 :: Double)
```

Unfortunately, this results in a more mysterious error, and still doesn't give me a stack trace :(

```
$ ghc -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto testNaN.hs && ./testNaN +RTS -xc
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testNaN.hs, testNaN.o )
Linking testNaN ...
testNaN: too many pending signals
```

I also tried using multiple threads. Most of the time the following happens.

```
$ ghc -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto -threaded testNaN.hs && ./testNaN +RTS -xc -N2
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( testNaN.hs, testNaN.o )
Linking testNaN ...
testNaN: lost signal due to full pipe: 8

testNaN: lost signal due to full pipe: 8

testNaN: lost signal due to full pipe: 8

... repeat many many times, very very fast
```

Although, once this happened.
http://pastebin.com/u3u2cnHE

Am I taking the right approach? Is there a way to modify my example so that I can get a stack trace?

Comment: GHC 8 has stack traces.  1. Use those traces.  2. Make a newtype wrapper that checks for NAN and +/- infinity then throws exceptions.

Comment: If performance is not relevant, definfing a `newtype` with a custom definition for `Num, RealFrac` looks simpler than dealing with signals. I'm still curious if using signals is actually possible, though.